# I got error on xcode7.3 when I tried to convert my codes from xcode7.2

Tags: swift, xcode7.3

I got error when I converted my codes from xcode7.2 to 7.3. The error I get says that `cannot convert value of type 'NSString' to expected argument type 'String!'`Does anyone know how to fix this? I really need your help.

```
let text = snapshot.value["text"] as? NSString
            let sender = snapshot.value["from"] as? NSString
            let name = snapshot.value["name"] as? NSString

            var isOutGoing:Bool

            if sender == GetUserId(){
                isOutGoing = true
            }else{
                isOutGoing = false
            }

            let mediaItem = self.createPhotoItem(Const.S3_URL + (text! as String), isOutgoing: isOutGoing)

            var message:JSQMessage
            if text!.hasSuffix(".jpg"){
                message = JSQMessage(senderId: sender, displayName: name, media: mediaItem)

            }else{
                message = JSQMessage(senderId: sender, displayName: name, text: text)
            }
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for not mentioning that. There two codes I got error for. Can you check the two codes under "if text!.hasSuffix(".jpeg")"? The codes start from "message".

Comment: matt? you dont know how to fix this?

Comment: With that attitude you might not get many answers. – It is *you* who needs help, and did not provide necessary information. What is `snapshot` and `snapshot.value`? What type has `snapshot.value["text"]`? What is `JSQMessage`? Is all that code really *relevant* or can you reduce it to a minimal example demonstrating the problem? ...

Comment: I dont know. problem is here "JSQMessage(senderId: sender" I changed some but didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new String form the NSString:

```
let regularString = myNSString as String
```

So you would use

```
displayName: name as String
```

Comment: message = JSQMessage(senderId: sender, displayName: name, media: mediaItem)

            }else{
                message = JSQMessage(senderId: sender, displayName: name, text: text)
            }

Comment: Sorry; you need to do the reverse. Let me edit my answer

Comment: I tried that already but didn't work... Thank you for ur help. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Telling me it doesn't work isnt helpful. What isnt working? What errors are you getting?